# bash - find: missing argument to `-exec' error

Tags: bash

I am trying to clean some files with the help of find command but getting a strange error in the below scenario.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -newermt 2011-01-01 ! -newermt 2012-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

Works fine without any error.
But when i put a simple completion message throws the below error.See the code below

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -newermt 2011-01-01 ! -newermt 2012-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
echo "completed"
```

Is there any syntax error i am making.

Comment: What /Where is the error?

Comment: You could combine statements like `find . -type f -newermt 2011-01-01 ! -newermt 2012-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \; ; echo "Hello"` (or) `find . -type f -newermt 2011-01-01 ! -newermt 2012-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \; && echo "Hello"`

Comment: The second piece of code in the question where there is a echo after the find command gives error.Strange thing id if i remove the echo command at last it works fine.

Comment: You wan to know if the truncate has happened and log a message for each file? Is that right?

Comment: find . -type f -newermt 2011-01-01 ! -newermt 2012-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \; ; echo "Hello"    ===> This worked for me.Thanks a lot for the help.It was eating my head for about 1 hr.

Comment: You never said what the error was. The code you posted looks fine.

Comment: Sorry for that .. You can view the error in the question itsef.Also for your reference i got the below error `find: missing argument to `-exec' `. Also just to update you i got it resolved by the suggestions below from  @Inian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` command's exit-code and print the error message based on that.

```
find . -type f -newermt 2011-01-01 ! -newermt 2012-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \; && echo "File truncation done"
```

(or) just run the commands sequentially as

```
find . -type f -newermt 2011-01-01 ! -newermt 2012-01-01 -exec truncate -s 0 {} \; ; echo "File truncation done"
```

(or) you can use an `echo` message after truncation of each file as

```
find . -type f -newermt 2011-01-01 ! -newermt 2012-01-01 -exec bash -c 'file="{}"; truncate -s 0 "$file"; echo "$file" is truncated' \;
```